# Windows 10 Hyper-V keep crashing

Tags: hyper-v, windows-10

I have a Windows 10 build 1511 host, running a Hyper-V guest of Windows 10 build 1511 as well.

The guest runs fine on Standard Mode. However, as soon as I switch to Enhanced Session mode, the `VMConnect.exe` process crashes. It happens with RDP too.

Anybody knows a workaround ?

Here are the EventViewer errors:

Error Source: Application Error

```
Faulting application name: VmConnect.exe, version: 10.0.10586.0, time stamp: 0x5632cee7
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 10.0.10586.20, time stamp: 0x56540c3b
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00000000000ab4a0
Faulting process id: 0x10d0
Faulting application start time: 0x01d150b20a36474c
Faulting application path: C:\WINDOWS\system32\VmConnect.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
Report Id: 828888e1-9a00-485c-af4a-643026a484f8
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Error Source: .NET Runtime

```
Application: VmConnect.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: exception code c0000005, exception address 00007FF958DBB4A0
```

Comment: capture a crash dump (see the steps here: http://pastebin.com/zKuJvw57) and share (post onedrive share link here) the ompressed dmp

Answer (score -1):

WOW, is this really 2 years old issue unsolved by Microsoft?
They are really good on bug fixing :(
I have same issue after a fresh install on win 11.

```
Faulting application name: VmConnect.exe, version: 10.0.22621.1, time stamp: 0xaad5fb25
Faulting module name: LMFX1N4Z.DLL, version: 0.0.1.0, time stamp: 0x61b8cf09
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0000000000038ac3
Faulting process ID: 0x0x11AC
Faulting application start time: 0x0x1D93EC841376850
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\system32\VmConnect.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\spool\DRIVERS\x64\3\LMFX1N4Z.DLL
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

So the error is related to the LMFX1N4Z.DLL dll, which is provided by Lexmark driver, so by turn off printer share with the VM it will stop crashing.